# What is system.in

Tags: java

Consider this `Scanner` input example.

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
```

Here `Scanner` is the CLASS.
`user_input` is the OBJECT under Scanner class. 
What is (`System.in`)? Is it a parameter passed or a object under `Scanner` class?.

Consider another example.

```
dog dog1 = new dog(25)
```

Here I have set dog class to accept size as a parameter.

What exactly is `System.in`?

Comment: Rather than the question `What is system.in`, I believe, you should first understand, what are constructor parameters. In ur sample, `new Scanner(System.in)`, it is calling the Scanner constructor and passing system.in as a parameter. And System.in is the standard input stream - typically keyboard.

Comment: `System.in` is an object. That object is passed as argument to the `Scanner` constructor (more precisely, a reference to it is).

Comment: Who are you give a negative vote??? Please encourage others to ask questions. if you don't like, just ignore...

Answer (score 12):

Scanner class accepts input stream as a parameter and System class have a static variable `in` which is of type `InputStream`. `System.in` gives you a instance of of type `InputStream`.

Check this [`doc of public static final InputStream in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in)

> The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. So system.in is a parameter in scanner class to accept input.

Comment: @user3762764 Yes. The stream helps you to get the input to the Scanner class.

Answer (score 10):

From  the [source](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html#system-in):

> System.in is an InputStream which is typically connected to keyboard
>   input of console programs. System.in is not used as often since data
>   is commonly passed to a command line Java application via command line
>   arguments, or configuration files. In applications with GUI the input
>   to the application is given via the GUI. This is a separate input
>   mechanism from Java IO.

Answer (score 8):

`System.in` is the "standard" input stream.

Take a look at the following documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: I do understand that. How is it passed in scanner class?

Comment: Because the scanner's constructor can take an inputStream: `Scanner(InputStream source)`. Take a look at the following documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html.

Comment: It would be better if we could add more explaination directly in the reply.

Answer (score 5):

`System.in` - "in" is object of class InputStream which is defined as static variables in class "System" which is used to read data from the console. In short "System.in" gives you a instance of of type InputStream.

When we create a Scanner class object we need to pass "System.in" as parameter in Scanner class Constructor. So basically using "System.in" Scanner class becomes able to read the data from console and then using different methods which are provided by Scanner class (like nextInt(), nextLong(), next() etc.), we can get data in the form of our desired datatypes (like int, double, String etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Scanner class has a constructor Scanner(InputStream) in its profile i.e when we call Scanner() constructor during the object creation time it will let you to pass the object of InputStream class.

"in" is an object of "InputStream" class defined in System class(like "out" is an object of PrintStream class defined in System class).

Thus System.in is nothing but calling the "in" object of InputStream class defined in System class when Scanner constructor is called during object creation time.

Scanner(InputStream) is pre-defined constructor in Scanner class which when calls requires the object of InputStream class as the parameter and that object is System.in.

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner constructor's parameter *System.in* references the static InputStream field *in* defined in the final System class. As a static field *in* requires its class identifier.

Oracle states that *in* is the "standard" input stream[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html), not that System.in is. The quotes around standard likely refer to the irony that inputting from a keyboard using a command line interface is no longer *the* standard, what with them newfangled GUIs and all.

Answer (score 0):

*"System.in"* is a parameter that is taken by Scanner Class where *"System"* is a class and *"in"* is a static variable of type InputStream which tells the Java Compiler that *System input* will be provided through console(keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

`System.in` is actually an InputStream typically connected to keyboard input of console programs.

Along with it you have direct access also to two other streams `System.out` and `System.err`.

`System.in`, `System.out` and `System.err` are initialized by the Java runtime when a Java VM starts.

Answer (score 0):

`in` is a static reference variable defined inside `System` class.
It is referring to `InputStream` object which is already connected with the command prompt.

It is roughly defined like this:

```
class System {
    static InputStream in=new InputStream();
}
```

Comment: Yes both 'System' and ' in'  are public as per documents of oracle.

Answer (score -1):

`System.in` in java means to take input from the keyboard or user.
`System.out` in java means to print the output to console.