# Scanner not actually taking in user input

Tags: java

I've tried different uses for Scanners (I want it to read in Files but I also tried just Strings), and it just skips over the code as if it doesn't exist. No error messages are shown.

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
      throws FileNotFoundException {
      
      Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
      String testLine = test.next();

      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));

      while(input.hasNextLine){
         String name = input.nextLine();
         String letters = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println(name + ": " + letters);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Post a sample of your input file.

Comment: What are the contents of `data.txt`?  It should have a number of lines that is a multiple of two, and it should not be empty.  And where is the file located?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile, because `hasNextLine()` is a function, not a class member.

You are actually reading from `System.in` at `test.next();` - you have to enter some text, then your code will continue to run. It's just waiting for a user input - thus no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

At this line of code:

```
String testLine = test.next();
```

your program is waiting for your input. It cannot proceed to next line till you provide an input.

**EDIT:** 
Taking cue from Charlie's comment below, here is a quote about `System.in` from [docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

> The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.

More [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786399/what-is-system-in/24786425).

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, but I wish to point out that `test.next()` does not open an input stream, it merely reads from `System.in`, which was already open when the program started.  It is waiting for input *on* `System.in`, though.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Thanks for the point out, Charlie! Actually, I wanted to jump directly to what was stopping the flow code with little intro to how. Edited the answer to make it more helpful.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll admit it was a bit of a nitpick ;)