# I am trying to use scanner class by passing java.io.InputStream variable

Tags: java, system.in

A question from core java.
I am trying to use scanner class by passing java.io.InputStream variable just like System.in. I dissemble java.io.System class and I found that a field is declared as ***"public static final java.io.InputStream in;"*** so I also declared a filed of same type as "myin". but it is giving compile time error stating that - error:variable myin might not have been initialized.
I just wanted to know how can I declared "in" and "out" variable of my own. Please help me out. any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class Test
{
  public static final java.io.InputStream myin;
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    int i;  
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(Test.myin);
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    i = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i);  
 } 
}
```

Comment: Initialise `myin = System.in`

Comment: Thanks aditya..  in is the same type of variable as I have created myin. In System class there is a in variable of same type what I am creating.. then I am not able to understand the need of such type of initialization.

Comment: There isn't a need to initialise your own variable for taking input.

Comment: Check this - [What is System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786399/what-is-system-in/24786425#:~:text=System.in%20is%20an%20InputStream,line%20arguments%2C%20or%20configuration%20files.&text=This%20is%20a%20separate%20input%20mechanism%20from%20Java%20IO.)

Answer (score 1):

The final modifier means that the variable has to be initialized exactly once, but you don't initialize it at all. However in your case, the variable is not needed, you can initialize the Scanner with `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`.

Comment: Thank you sir.. I am trying to create something like System.in... To pass in scanner class.. why can't I pass myin variable which is declared same as in declared in System class.. In above code, how can I initialize myin field? If I successfully cloned System.in then I will clone System.out  something like Test.myout then println() method will be called with it. Later on I will write my own scanner class.. I can't do without you gentleman..Plz help me and suggest me possibilities and I will try it..

Comment: @Pushkar: As @AdityaArora already said in the comments, `myin = System.in`.

Comment: That is not working.. and more over why I use System.in... I am trying to create my own version of System.in.. it doesn't make sense to pass System.in to make another version of same.

Comment: It is not like instead of passing variable a I write b=a and passing b.. I don't want this.. I want to creat a independent variable b which can be passed.

Comment: @Pushkar: Why do you not want this when it solves your problem? Can you explain more about your specific circumstandes? This should work perfectly fine.